# How long to program a FPGA - seconds, microseconds, less?

Tags: fpga

How long does it take to load a new configuration on a FPGA? can a FPGA be re-programmed on the fly while a computer program with offloads to the FPGA is running?

Comment: how big and via JTAG, flash or eeprom?  A Virtext5 boots from NVM->SRAM takes 500ms. An Actel APA1000 programmed via FlashPro or FlashproLite takes 40min to program ("boots in us"). An A3P1000 takes 3min to program

Comment: The fastest way is to use an internal reconfiguration port (e.g ICAP in Xilinx FPGAs). This offers a 32 bit interface running at 100 MHz => 3.2 GBps. A typical bitfile has for ex. 20 MiB => 100 ms per bit file. This can be improved by enabling bitfile compression. P.S. in this scenario the data is streamed via PCIe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, it's usually one or two seconds or at least 100's of milliseconds.

It depends on how big is the FPGA and what interface (serial, parallel, etc) you use to program it.  The time remains relatively constant as FPGA technology improves because as the FPGAs get bigger, they also add new higher-speed programming interfaces.

To know for sure, divide the length of the bit stream by the bit rate of the programming interface you want to use. If you're programming from a computer host, add some time to account for the computer not devoting all its resources to filling the pipe from it to the FPGA.

Comment: Basically, if you're programming "from afar", add a factor, because many programming routines actually have to wait for the programming of a piece of bitstream to be finished before starting the next. This adds a lot of dead time to the programming process, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

> can a FPGA be re-programmed on the fly while a computer program with offloads to the FPGA is running?

That is called *partial reconfiguration*, and is possible, under rare circumstances, namely, that you use the right tools (with pricey licenses), and partition your FPGA design accordingly, have made provisions that clocking the used parts runs on, and the moon phase is just right.

Comment: Partial reconfiguration (at least in Xilinx-land) is much more standard than it used to be - you have to have the right devices and tools (but I don't think they have to be the pricey ones) and the deisgn must be planned with PR in mind from the start.  But I think the moon-phase doesn't matter any more :)

Comment: Coming late, but assuming this is done, what would be the time to update a configuration?

Comment: @LOST that completely depends on the FPGA and the size of the reconfigured area. Refer to the datasheet of your FPGA and your experience on how fast you can expect to configure it using its configuration interfaces. Might be milliseconds, might be minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> can a FPGA be re-programmed on the fly while a computer program with
>   offloads to the FPGA is running?

This is an old question, but I'll quickly include the Active Serial programming method, where the FPGA loads its image from a flash memory, and then the flash memory can be re-programmed at runtime while the FPGA is up, and then the FPGA will pick up the new image on the next reset.

With this method, a new image can be loaded while the FPGA is currently running, and you can even have multiple images on the flash and choose between them if required.